# Google Analytics api access with PHP nightmare

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I need your help because I'm writting a little CMS for my clients and I need to integrate the google analytics data on the admin dashboard. Like number of visits etc. So was using GAPI librairy but it seems that it's going to be deprecated to use it with API V3.

My problem is that when I read the Google Analytics API with OAuth etc, it looks like you have to configure a lot of thing just to get the analytics datas... And I can't ask my future client to do all that steps... I saw some website that were more simple you just had to click on a button on the first time you use it and it will open a Google page that ask you if you give this website the access to you Analytics data... That can be good for me, but I can't find how they did that in the Doc...

Can you please give me way of making a simple call to the API to get this data ?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api#introduction is a really good source to see how access using oauth2 through php. Have you set up oauth2 in the Google Cloud service?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem is that I will give this to all my client and doen't want them to have to configure all this OAuth2 part...